# What are all the short codes for svn commands?

Tags: svn, command-line

I know that `co` can be used as shorthand for `checkout`, and through experimentation I have found `di` is short for `diff` and `st` short for `status`. Are there shortened codes for all svn commands? If so what are they?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typing `svn help` shows a list of all available commands and their shortcuts:

```
Available subcommands:
(Only those with 2-letter short-codes listed)

   changelist (cl)
   checkout   (co)
   commit     (ci)
   copy       (cp)
   delete     (rm)
   diff       (di)
   help       (h)
   list       (ls)
   move       (mv)
   propdel    (pd)
   propedit   (pe)
   propget    (pg)
   proplist   (pl)
   propset    (ps)
   status     (st)
   switch     (sw)
   update     (up)
```