# How to delete folder from subversion tags directory?

Tags: svn

I have an extra folder in my subversion tags directory. The wierd part is, I dont see it when I `ls` in that folder since I deleted it the tags directory in my terminal. But when I look at the subversion website it is still there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer link http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html

```
svn delete <dir>
svn ci <dir> -m "comment"
```

Comment: ci means commit. for more details refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989765/what-are-all-the-short-codes-for-svn-commands